# FFMPEG filter_complex wih speedup and subtitles and scaling

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, command-line-tool

Hi I am trying to convert a file to a specific framerate and remove any jittering, jumping of the screen. I also try to boost the volume and add a subtitle overlay. I get an error with the curent line than it is not allowed to use complex_filter in combination with vf and af. as an extra I also would like to add text in the left corner (this i did not try yet) and would want the screen to be sized to full hd (changed scale to 1920:1080 but no succes).

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -r 25 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.959*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.0427[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vf subtitles=sub.srt,scale=1920:1080 -af volume=2 -strict -2 -preset veryfast movie_new.mp4
```

Got it!

New:

```
ffmpeg -i inside.mp4 -r 25 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.959*PTS[i];[i]scale=1920:1080[j];[j]subtitles=inside.srt[k];[0:a]atempo=1.0427[p];[p]volume=2[q]" -map "[k]" -map "[q]" -strict -2 -preset veryfast inside_new.mp4
```

But now there is a new issue. Subs out of sync :P is there a easy fix for this or do i first need to encode without subs then resync then encode with subs?

found this link by the way [Subtitle Resync Tool](http://subshifter.bitsnbites.eu/)

moviespeed is changed by 0.959. is there a calculation i can do to adjust the subtitles by x miliseconds?

EDIT: Got the subtitles fixed with subtitle workshop. Was just a small setting to change which directly shifted all the text :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below command as ffmpeg restricts using `-vf` and `-af` options to use with `-filter_complex`:

```
    ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -i sub.srt -r 25 -filter_complex \
           "[0:v]setpts=0.959*PTS[i];[i]scale=1920:1080[j];[j][1:s]overlay[k];\
            [0:a]atempo=1.0427[p];[p]volume=2[q]" -map "[k]" -map "[q]" \
            -strict -2 -preset veryfast movie_new.mp4
```

- `[0:v]` refers to first input i.e, movie.mp4
- `[1:s]` refers to second input i.e., subtitles input file (sub.srt)

Filters need to be concatenated in the desired fashion, not necessarily as above. Actually `-vf` and `-af` serve the same purpose as `-filter_complex`, but in simplest manner. That's why ffmpeg resticts using `-filter_complex` in combination with `-vf` and/or `-af`

Comment: THanks but the overlay filter in your command wont work with text based subtitles. I get the error "sub2video: non-bitmap subtitle" now. The rest seem to work fine. also encoding is slower is that due to the command or did the preset not work?

Comment: May be remove overlay option and instead use "-scodec copy" option or some thing similar options for moving sub-title text to video output

Comment: allright got it!
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -r 25 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.959*PTS[i];[i]scale=1920:1080[j];[j]subtitles=movie.srt[k];[0:a]atempo=1.0427[p];[p]volume=2[q]" -map "[k]" -map "[q]" -strict -2 -preset veryfast movie_new.mp4

but now there is a different issue i knew i would get :) because the move speed is changed and the audiospeed. the subtitles are out of sync...Now..Do i need to convert first then a second time after resyncing the subs? 2 times converting or is there a easier way?

Comment: THe aspect ratio did not change. I forced the scale 1920:1080 to remove the black bars but it did not change anything. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Added -aspect 16:9 fixed it. image is a bit disorted maybe cutting from the sides a bit would be better?

Comment: I understand your problem almost got solved, except the distortion issue. Is this distortion observed due to scaling or something else?

Comment: By default, FFMPEG uses bi-cubic algo for scaling. May be you could try with other algos like sinc, lanczos, spline etc. and decide on one that suits your purpose. But, keep in mind that better video quality comes at a cost of CPU performance.

Comment: Is there a similar property like setpts or atempo for subtitles?